# Environment Media Features Support

Tags: css, media-queries

So according to dev.w3.org this is a thing:

```css
@media (light-level: normal) {
  p { background: url("texture.jpg"); color: #333 }
}
@media (light-level: dim) {
  p { background: #222; color: #ccc }
}
@media (light-level: washed) {
  p { background: white; color: black; font-size: 2em; }
}
```

It lets you adjust CSS according to the light level of the device. I went through some articles but couldn't find anything about support. I was wondering what the support of these media queries are? Are they already implemented on some browsers?

Source:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries4/#light-level

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries -- for the farther-future and 3 versions ahead looks like chrome and ff might be your only hope in using these right now. Since they are part of a spec that's still being written, more than likely you'll find early adopters in chrome, ff, and maybe ie10. If this isn't working in chrome, ff, the previous spec called it "luminosity" instead of light-level ex: http://www.jordanm.co.uk/post/65776639602/responding-to-environmental-lighting-with-css-media

Comment: You should add that as an answer @Brodie. That was pretty concise.

Comment: Saying "according to W3C this is a thing" is taking it pretty far. It's most certainly *not* a thing until there is some generally available implementation. Every ED begins with the following disclaimer: "This is a public copy of the editors’ draft. It is provided for discussion only and may change at any moment. Its publication here does not imply endorsement of its contents by W3C. Don’t cite this document other than as work in progress." And the Media Queries 4 spec itself is relatively new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ moving to answer per peoples suggestions ]

http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries -- for the farther-future and 3 versions ahead looks like chrome and ff might be your only hope in using these right now. Since they are part of a spec that's still being written, more than likely you'll find early adopters in chrome, ff, and maybe ie10. If this isn't working in chrome, ff, the previous spec called it "luminosity" instead of light-level ex: http://www.jordanm.co.uk/post/65776639602/responding-to-environmental-lighting-with-css-media